# Android Studio Sunshine App

Tags: android-studio

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code and why my Sunshine App won't display the list items I created.

Most of my code is the same as the code in the videos but some of it is different by default as I am using an updated version of Android Studio.  How can I display the random forecast data in a list?  All I get when running my code is the Name of the app in the action bar.

Below are the files I coded in:

MainActvityFragment.java:

```
package com.example.ashton.sunshine.app;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/46",
                "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Rainy - 64/51",
                "Fri - Foggy - 70/46",
                "Sat - Sunny - 76/68"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

fragment_main.xml -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

activity_main.xml -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.ashton.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

list_item_forecast.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml, change`FrameLayout` to `fragment`

Comment: I did that and I look at the Design tab on the activity_main.xml and it only shows an empty list with "item1" then below "Item 2", then below that "Item 3", etc.  I think my issue is that the adapter is not properly connecting the forecastArray up correctly.  How do I connect these properly?

Comment: The design tab is only to give you an idea of how things will look when you run the app. It won't show you the data from 'your forecastArray'. To see the data being loaded, you need to run the app.

Comment: I ran it and just like before, I get a blank screen with the name of the app in the action bar

Answer (score 0):

This is an openweathermap api issue. It's really slow sometimes for free accounts.

Use local wifi, that should speed up the response. And try it at a different time of day. That's the only advice that I can give you.